# Mailchimp address field in update form (advanced customiser)

Tags: mailchimp

I'm creating a custom update form and I want to display address information using MERGE tags.

I can find no information on how to display the Address subfields (Address 1, Address 2, City, etc.). I thought it might be along the lines of

```
value="*|MERGE3[addr1]|*"
```

e.g.

```
<tr>
  <td align="right" class="formLabel">Address</td>
  <td align="left">
    <div class="field-wrapper">
      <div class="addressfield">
        <span class="subfield addr1field">
          <label for="MERGE3-addr1"></label>
          <input type="text" id="MERGE3-addr1" name="MERGE3[addr1]" maxlength="70" value="*|MERGE3[addr1]|*" placeholder="" class="av-text">
        </span>
....
```

But this literally prints

> value="*|MERGE3[addr1]|*"

in the update form field for Address 1. Can anyone help? It would be useful to know if it's even possible.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried `value="*|MERGE3:addr1|*"`?

Comment: I have just tried - it doesn't work. Neither does     value="*|MERGE3-addr1|*"